# Android: how to create this kind of dynamic layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

My aim is to display people/addresses in a list - but not just a simple list, rather a list of boxes that contain several information, in my case a number, the address and a type:

[image]

The data structure for this are POJOs:

- **MyPojo.java (Class)**
- + getNumer()
- + getType()
- + getName()
- + getStreet()
- + getCity()

Of course, there are more than 4 entries which means that there should be a scrollbar. My first idea: a `Scrollview` that contains a `Linear Layout`. But I'm not sure about the content, means the boxes you can see above.

1. How can I define such boxes that represent the list items? As you can see above, a box consists of three parts that are divided from each other (Number, Type, Address).
2. Of course, it must be possible to add and remove boxes (means: entries) dynamically at runtime to the Linear Layout.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> `My first idea: a Scrollview that contains a Linear Layout.`

Are you familiar with a [`listView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)? This already exists to do exactly that. I'm sure you can find dozens of tutorials on how to use them by searching.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. But I was not sure if I only can add text as list-item to a listView or also more complex UI elements (as mentionned, my "list elements" are that boxes instead of plain text).

Comment: You can add pretty much anything as the 'list-objects' in a listview. Custom views, hierarchies of multiple views, etc. I won't write a tutorial here but I'm sure you can find one.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `ListActivity` class
- Create a separate layout file for your item

  `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical" >
          <TextView />
          <TextView />
      </LinearLayout>
      </TextView>
  </LinearLayout>`
- Then Create an inner class in `ListActivity` which extends from `ArrayAdapter`. In the `getView()` method, use `LayoutInflater` to inflate yourItemLayout and update the TextView based on the `position` values.
- From `onCreate` in the main class, call `setListAdapter(new InnerClass(this,R.layout.yourItemLayout,list)`

You can refer [customArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/721932) to know how to custom ArrayAdapter works.

Done and dusted.